# Using Ruby's popen3 or equivalent on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, process, popen3

I'm making a Vim plugin that uses `Open3.popen3` to run a shell command, and I need the result and exit code. It works fine on Linux, but freezes on Windows. I've checked on `pry` under Windows and whenever I run `Open3.popen3` or `Process.spawn` the shell just freezes. I've tried to install the `win32-open3-19` gem(and load it with `require 'win32/open3`) - but it still freezes.

Is there any other method or gem I can use? I prefer something as close as possible to `Open3`(so my Linux and Windows versions can share as much code as possible).

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3 installed via RubyInstaller on Windows 7 64bit.

**MORE DETAILS**:

This is the exact code I want to run: https://github.com/someboddy/vim-erroneous/blob/master/autoload/erroneous.rb#L43

It works on Linux but freezes on Windows.

On my Windows, I open `pry` and then write:

```
require 'win32/open3'
inp,out,err,wait_thr=Open3.popen3('cmd')
```

And my shell freezes. When I try it on Linux(using 'bash' instead of 'cmd') it works just fine. I've also tried 'dir'(which shouldn't wait for user input) and it also froze.

Comment: `Open3` works on windows. Which command are you trying to execute?

Comment: You need to show a sample of the code you're trying to run.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details

Comment: works for me, either `o, e, s = Open3.capture3(cmd)` or `Open3.popen3(cmd) {|i, o, e, t| t.value }` on Windows 8.1 with ruby 1.9.3.